# No Users Or Groups Folders In VisualSVN Server

Tags: windows, svn, visualsvn-server

[image: Main page with no folders for users or groups]

I have downloaded VisualSVN Server, version 5.1.1. In the left panel there is only Repositories and Jobs. I want to add new users for learing and testing purposes. However I can't see any settings to do so. *I currently dont have a licence. Is this the main reason?* If not, how can I enable Users and Groups folders or how can I reach to related settings? **Keep in mind that I'm a completely newbie to this application. Any help is appreciated, thanks**

I have tried to find related settings in autentication properties but I got confused and bogged down. I have tried to open the application as Administrator, still couldn't find or make sense of settings.
I also tried to find subversion authentication settings which is normally in the main page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the MMC snap-in, you should have a ***Users*** option down the left hand side of the tree.  However, on the main Visual SVN page, you have various options, one of which should be ***Subversion Authentication***.  You can also add users and groups using the options here also (see below, for a screen shot of my SVN Server).  Regarding the license, that shouldn't be an issue, as long as your requirement fits withing the "Community" licensing requirements.

If you don't see options to Create Users / Groups, use the ***Configure Authentication Options*** and set the ***Authentication Mode*** to ***Subversion Authentication***.  This will allow subversion to authenticate users based on a list that is setup within the server itself.  Hope that Helps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir. This was the correct answer for my case

Answer (score 0):

The Users and Groups folders are only available in the management console when your server is configured to use the standalone Subversion authentication mode. When this authentication mode is active, your server maintains a dedicated list of user and group accounts.

However, your screenshot shows that you've enabled Windows authentication. In this case, your server integrates with your Active Directory domain / Windows, and user and group accounts are maintained by Active Directory. I.e., you don't need to create users and groups in VisualSVN Server. They are already created in your domain and you can grant permissions to these accounts via the management console.

You can find more information about the authentication modes in the article [KB182: VisualSVN Server authentication modes](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00182/).

Comment: Thanks for feedback, this was also helpfull. In my case, other user and group accounts belongs to the company and I didn't want to mess with anyone's accounts :)